# Trouble installing rails in Mac OS 10.8.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install RoR following  railstutorial.org which is pretty similar to this one: http://www.creativereason.com/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-mountain-lio.html

But, when i type "gem install rails" in command, i'm getting this error and couldn't install RoR.

I'm getting this error:

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Does someone know how to fix this and install rails correctly?

Comment: check this link http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2010/9/23/install-rails-ruby-mac

Comment: Unfornutally, the railsInstaller is not installing RoR and it shows the sam error above

Answer (score 0):

Install RVM and ruby:

$ curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Then Rails:

`rvm gem install rails`

Comment: I don't follow, your q title says Trouble installing rails.  If rails is installed, are you looking to make a new project with `rails new abcd`?

Comment: No. Im having problem installing rails. RVM and Ruby are already installed but im having problem trying to install rails

Comment: What happens when you type `rvm gem install rails` ?

Comment: See note on other answer.  My advice at this point to try and help you is a new question.  I hope you find an answer. Best of luck :)

Comment: This is the error that I Got: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28887/discussion-between-cleyton-and-michael-durrant)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that rubygems is out of date:

```
gem install rubygems-update
```

and/or

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: The same error occurs when I run those commands. I've already tried

Comment: Can you browse sites normally?  Also, if you are getting errors updating rubygems then your problems are probably with that or elsewhere and nothing to do with rails.

Comment: I would take the `gem update --system` and the exact error you get and post it as a new question.  That will probably have a better chance of success at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I had to disable Avast antivirus! Now, it's working!